# Router push sometimes pushes [object Object] in url path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, path, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm building an universal app with NuxtJS. I'm not an expert but I used Nuxt and Vue many times before but I still cannot figure out why it's doing it.

The app also Vuex to store data.

The logic of the app is:
In page 1 i have my favorites and a search bar. (favorites list and search results have the same component to show the element and to click on it to see it's content).
If i click on this component-box it runs 
`` this.$router.push(`/orario/viewer/${this.id}`) `` 
where `this.id` is the id of the element to show and also the id that has to be put on the url to perform the query on the 2 page.

Now we come to the problem.
If i click on a favorite, let's say the id is ABC, it opens http://localhost:8000/orario/viewer/ABC, which is fine, it is what i want and it works expectedly.
The problems comes when i click on an element after i received it from a search query from another api, because, even if it runs the same function and it pushes the same path, in the address bar it shows: 
http://localhost:8000/orario/viewer/[object Object], so then I cannot do anything because I'm not able to access the ID.

I put a log right before to push the route (`console.log(this.id, typeof this.id)`)
Both if clicked a favorite or after the search it prints ABC, String, but the first time it works as expected (page path is: http://localhost:8000/orario/viewer/ABC) instead the second the page path is: http://localhost:8000/orario/viewer/[object Object]

Comment: You must be doing something that's setting `this.id` to an object. Post your actual code, there's no way to tell from your description what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem when pushing an object to the query string, and it shows as `[Object Object]`